# Java -- static & dynamic type -- "what does this print?"

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, dynamic, static

So I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this example that was shown in class -- it's supposed to illustrate subtleties between static & dynamic types in Java.

```
public class Piece {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Piece p2 = new Knight();
        Knight p1 = new Knight();
        p1.capture(p2); // call 1; "Knight is bored" is supposed to be printed
        p2.capture(p1); // call 2; "knight is bored" is supposed to be printed
    }

    public void capture () {
        System.out.println("Capturing");
    }

    public void capture (Piece p) {
        System.out.println("I'm bored")
    }

public class Knight extends Piece {

    public void capture (Piece p) {
        System.out.println("Knight is bored");
    }

    public void capture (Knight k) {
        System.out.println("TOO SLOW BUDDY");
    }
}
```

Here's my understanding of what happens when the two calls get made:

Call 1: p1.capture(p2)

The capture method is called from p1.  Via dynamic type lookup, it sees that p1's dynamic type is **Knight**. So it looks in the Knight subclass. p2 is passed in as an argument. To see which capture method to invoke within the Knight subclass, it checks the **static** type of p2, which is **piece**. Therefore, "Knight is Bored" is printed. This is the right output, but is my reasoning correct?

Call 2: p2.capture(p1)

Using the same reasoning, the capture method is called from p2. Via dynamic type lookup, it sees that p2's dynamic type is **Knight**. So it looks in the Knight subclass. p1 is passed in as an argument. To see which capture method to invoke, it looks at p1's static type, which is **Knight**. Therefore, "TOO SLOW BUDDY" is printed. Obviously, my reasoning is wrong, as that's not what's really printed. Any direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second call, you can only call methods of the Piece class or the same methods in its subclasses. That's why it will call capture(Piece p) instead of capture(Knight k). The latter is specific to the Knight class.

For example, when we have "List a = new Arraylist();", you can only call methods that were declared in List, not additional but similar looking methods in ArrayList.

Comment: Hmmmm. So because p2's static type is that of a Piece, it only knows the capture(Piece p) method, and not the capture(Knight k) method? How then, is it able to go into the Knight subclass and take that version of the method? Sorry, still a bit confused.

Comment: That's because Knight extends Piece and p2 is a Knight object. This means you can only call Piece methods but if Knight has a method with the same signature, it'll call that one instead.

Comment: Do you mean p2 is a object of type *Piece*?

Comment: @RyanYu: Yes, in the same way that `a` in my example is a `List` in the remaining code. But when methods are called on `a`, it is considered an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @RyanYu: I think p2 is a reference of type Piece and object of type Knight.. hope it answers you...

Answer (score 2):

When you add `@Override` annotation to `Knight`s methods it becomes clear.

```
public void capture (Knight k) {
    System.out.println("TOO SLOW BUDDY");
}
```

this method isn't overriden - **it's new**, added in `Knight` class.

So it could be used only on object with type `Knight` - for example: `Knight k = new Knight();`

You dont have such example, that this method is invoked on `Knight` with `Knight` as argument. You invoked `capture` on Knight with Piece, and on Piece with knight

```
    p1.capture(p2); // call 1; "Knight is bored" is supposed to be printed
    p2.capture(p1); // call 2; "knight is bored" is supposed to be printed
    p1.capture(p1); // call 3:  TOO SLOW BUDDY <- look here :)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. When you say "it could be used only on objects with type Knight," you refer to their static type, right? In other words, Knight n; would be of type knight.

Comment: @Ryan Yu, You have 2 thing - type of reference and dynamic object object: `Type staticTypeOfReference = new DynamicPolimorficObjectThatCanExtendTypeDeclared();` :)

Comment: Okay, so let me see if I have this right, finally: for p1.capture(p2), it sees p1 is of type Knight & p2 of type Piece, so it checks in the Knight subclass for a capture method that takes in a Piece as an argument. It finds this, and prints out "Knight is bored"

Comment: Furthermore, for p2.capture(p1), it sees p2 is of type Piece, and p1 is of size Knight. It looks within the class that capture is being called from (p2 -- Piece), and sees that there is no method that takes in an argument of type Knight. But there is a method that takes in an argument of type Piece! Dynamic lookup then tells the method to check in the subclass (Knight) for a method that overrides this capture method, which it finds. It then uses this overriding method to print "Knight is bored."

Comment: @Ryan Yu - `Furthermore, for p2.capture(p1), it sees p2 is of type Piece` - here type of p2 doesn't matter, it's being dinamically resolved to Knight, static resolving takes place when you pass obiect to some method - then static type is being checked, and actual reference to its subclass doen't matter at all. `p2.capcure(p1)` - this invokation knows that p2 is object of **Knight** class with reference type of Piece (but it doesn't matter here...) and it knows that p1 has reference type of (lest side of calling constructor) Knight, that is being subclass of Piece.

Comment: So p2 could invoke `capcure(Knight)` - that would suit the best - but `Piece` class has no such method, so next in row is `capture(Piece)` that is being present. So this one is called.

Answer (score 2):

```
 p2.capture(p1); // call 2; "knight is bored" is supposed to be printed
```

Here you are calling capture method on Piece class object and since you have passes p1(Knight) class reference it will call overridden capture method of class Knight. that is

```
 public void capture (Piece p) {
        System.out.println("Knight is bored");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following code -

```
public class Piece {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Piece p2 = new Knight();
    Knight p1 = new Knight();
    p1.capture(p2); 
    p2.capture(p1); 
}

public void capture () {
    System.out.println("Capturing");
}

public void capture (Piece p) {
    System.out.println("I'm bored");
}
```

}

```
  class Knight extends Piece {


  //    public void capture (Piece p) {
  //        System.out.println("Knight is bored");
  //    }

public void capture (Knight k) {
    System.out.println("TOO SLOW BUDDY"+k);
}
```

}

The result is  -

I'm bored

I'm bored

So the dynamic lookup checks if the subclass has overridden the function or not.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, I've learned "extending" means "laying the new one over the old one but not delete it" and if you are "override" the method, it would be like you described. 
In your case if you call "p1.capture(p1)" it should result in "TOO SLOW BUDDY" (but I did not tried).

Comment: Yeah, p1.capture(p1) results in "TOO SLOW BUDDY"; however, what I'm confused about are the other two cases, rather than this case ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this sample is telling you the deferences between static & dynamic type . You even need not to think about the superclass and subclass . It is just telling you the method definition . ---> Only when caller , method name , parameters' names and parameters' types are all the same , the right method will be called .